# Swift Navigation to Specific Child VC with tabBarControllers

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, tabbarcontroller

I have a setup with a tabBarController going to four navigation controllers which contain go further to some child view controllers. In this instance, I am trying to go to one of the child view controllers of the navigation controller. I've been able to transition tabBar pages with the code. 
self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 4
But after I need to go to perform a segue to a child view controller on from this page. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Overall tabBarController setup
[image]

Settings Tab Controller Page with child view controllers
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Store your tab bar child controllers as a property in an array in your `UITabBarController`, e.g.

```
var tabViewControllers: [UIViewController]!
```

2) After setting `self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = desiredIndex`, ask target child to perform desired actions.

```
let targetNavigationController = self.tabViewControllers[desiredIndex] as? UINavigationController
let yourTargetViewController = targetNavigationController?.viewControllers.first as? YourTargetViewController
// From here do whatever you want: call functions, perform segues, push to navigation stack or present modals, e.g.:
yourTargetViewController?.performSegue(...)
```

Comment: You are the man! Thank you so much! Seriously solved like a weeks worth of racking my brain! <3

Comment: @AlexHughes please accept the answer and upvote if it helped you :)

Comment: I accepted it but it won't let me upvote with my reputation. I got it working with what you suggested. But I'm also trying to do the same thing from a modal popup over on of the tabbar views. Would you know how to do this off the top of your head? Thank you so much!

Comment: @AlexHughes look for your modal vc at `yourTargetViewController.presentedViewController as? YourModalViewController`

Comment: I think I didn't describe it clear. While I'm on the modal popup viewcontroller, I'm trying to press a button. Dismiss the modal VC and than go to the target view controller and perfrom the segue. I just can't seem how to reference the root view controller below the modal popup.